# Using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol / Universal Analytics from Flash / AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, google-analytics, xss

I see that Google Analytics (as part of their new and [recommended](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro) Universal Analytics solution) provides a simple RESTful interface called the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) for collecting analytics from a variety of platforms or applications.

How do you use this interface from a Flash/AS3 app?  I'm creating a payload of url-formatted [parameters according to the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters), but I'm getting a `SecurityError` because `crossdomain.xml` is not hosted at `http://www.google-analytics.com/crossdomain.xml` when making the URL request:

```
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://<mysite>/<myapp>.swf cannot load data from http://www.google-analytics.com/collect."]
```

Using either POST or GET, this call fails in the context of a web browser (though it succeeds in the context of AIR):

```
// i.e. var payload:String = 'v=1&t=event&ec=category&ea=action'+
//   '&el=label&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect');
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = payload;
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(req);
```

I need these analytics to work from either AIR or the Flash Player (on a web page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is noted in the [URLRequest docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#contentType), cross-site scripting (xss) restrictions require a `crossdomain.xml` for POST requests.  Since google doesn't host this file, you have to avoid POST.  But the measurement protocol doc says it will accept either GET or POST.  So you have to use a GET.  GET with the above code still throws, but it turns out if you use a Loader instead of a URLLoader (as if you were going to access an image on the web, which is not covered by xss rules), it works:

```
// i.e. var payload:String = 'v=1&t=event&ec=category&ea=action'+
//   '&el=label&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?'+payload);
var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cleanup);
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cleanup);
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, cleanup);
l.load(req);
function cleanup(e:Event):void {
  l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cleanup);
  l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cleanup);
  l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, cleanup);
}
```

You want the error listeners so that no errors pop-up, and you also need to clean them up to prevent memory leaks.

However, on mobile, I'd still use your original `URLLoader` code (as it has fewer allocations / events), perhaps using conditional compilation:

```
// i.e. var payload:String = 'v=1&t=event&ec=category&ea=action'+
//   '&el=label&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

ENV::AIR {
  var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect');
  req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  req.data = payload;
  var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  urlLoader.load(req);
}

ENV::WEB {
  var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?'+payload);
  var l:Loader = new Loader();
  l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cleanup);
  l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cleanup);
  l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, cleanup);
  l.load(req);
  function cleanup(e:Event):void {
    l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, cleanup);
    l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cleanup);
    l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, cleanup);
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `URLStream` have the same issue with a cross-domain `GET` call that `URLLoader` does? I've never tested. They both use `URLRequest`, but the actual mechanism for making the request is completely separate, as far as I am aware.

Comment: I've never used `URLStream`, but I see [the doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) states:  _The security rules that apply to URL downloading with the URLStream class are identical to the rules applied to URLLoader objects. Policy files may be downloaded as needed._

Comment: Damn. Did not see that note. That is unfortunate

Answer (score 1):

or you can use a library
Google Universal Analytics for ActionScript 3.0

checkout as3-universal-analytics v0.8

https://github.com/zwetan/as3-universal-analytics/releases/tag/0.8

full support for: Flash Player, AIR, Redtamarin
it just works everywhere or almost everywhere :)

in your case

```
var config:Configuration = new Configuration();
    config.forcePOST = true;
var tracker:WebTracker = new WebTracker( "UA-12345-67", config );
    tracker.pageview( "/hello/world", "Hello World" );
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll look into that next time I need one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff has a good answer, but you can improve it by leveraging `POST` method, not `GET`, since GET is quite restricted and not good to send a big bunch of data.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = payload;
var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.load(req);
```

Notice `POST` request method, it will do the trick